# Rails help simple form: undefined method `model_name' for Hash:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

I am trying to create a form with the gem simple form.

The form should have a select list of all konkurrancers. And the action URL should be the controller public and action pricecompare and with the ID of the konkurrancer. My route: pricecombare/:id

My route.rb:

```
match "/finder/:id" => 'public#pricecompare'
```

My simple form so far:

```
<%= simple_form_for({:controller => "public", :action => "pricecompare"}, :method => "get") do |f| %>
<%= f.association :konkurrancer, :collection => Konkurrancer.all(:order => 'name'), :prompt => "Pick company" %>
<%= f.button :submit, :style => 'display: none;' %>
```

I get this error:

```
undefined method `model_name' for Hash:Class
```

The Html output I want:

```
<form method="post" id="new_konkurrancer" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="simple_form konkurrancer" action="/public/pricecompare" accept-charset="UTF-8">
<select style=" margin-left:10px;width:370px;float: left;
    margin-top: 10px;"name="konkurrancer[form]" id="konkurrancer_form" class="select optional"><option value="">Vælg din A-kasse:</option>
<option value="1">ASE</option>
<option value="2">Træ-industri-byg</option>
<option value="3">Journalistik, kommunikation og sprog</option>
<option value="4">Faglis fælles A-kasse (3F)</option>
<option value="5">Danske lønmodtagere</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Opret konkurrence" name="commit" id="konkurrancer_submit" class="button" style="display: none;">
```

**Updated:**

My public controller:

```
def index
@konkurrancer = Konkurrancer
end


def pricecompare
@akasse = Konkurrancer.where(params[:id]).first
@akasserne = Konkurrancer.order(sort_column + " " + sort_direction)
end

<%= simple_form_for(:konkurrancer, :url => {:controller => "finder"}, :method => "get") do |f| %>
  <%= f.association :konkurrancer, :collection => Konkurrancer.all(:order => 'name'), :prompt => "Pick company" %>
  <%= f.button :submit, :style => 'display: none;' %>
<% end %>
```

And I get this error in view:

```
ActionController::RoutingError in Public#index

Showing C:/Rails/akasse/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #95 raised:

No route matches {:controller=>"finder"}

Extracted source (around line #95):

92:                                 <%= render("shared/forside") %>
93:                         </div>
94: <div style="width:900px;float:left;margin-left:29px;margin-top:15px;"><p style="width:500px; float:left;font-weight:bolder;font-size:12px;margin-left:20px;font-family:verdana;">Find den billigeste a-kasse - Vælg din  a-kasse og se om du kan spare penge</p>
95: <%= simple_form_for(:konkurrancer, :url => {:controller => "finder"}, :method => "get") do |f| %>

ActionController::RoutingError in Public#index

Showing C:/Rails/akasse/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #95 raised:

No route matches {:controller=>"finder"}
```

Update NEW error log:

```
Association cannot be used in forms not associated with an object

Extracted source (around line #96):

93:                         </div>
94: <div style="width:900px;float:left;margin-left:29px;margin-top:15px;"><p style="width:500px; float:left;font-weight:bolder;font-size:12px;margin-left:20px;font-family:verdana;">Find den billigeste a-kasse - Vælg din  a-kasse og se om du kan spare penge</p>
95: <%= simple_form_for(:konkurrancer, :url => '/finder', :method => "post") do |f| %>
96:   <%= f.association :konkurrancer, :collection => Konkurrancer.all(:order => 'name'), :prompt => "Pick company" %>
97:   <%= f.button :submit, :style => 'display: none;' %>
98: <% end %>
99:
```

I have tried to change it to a instanse variable and get this error:

```
NoMethodError in Public#index

Showing C:/Rails/akasse/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #95 raised:

undefined method `to_key' for #<Class:0x85246c8>

Extracted source (around line #95):

92:                                 <%= render("shared/forside") %>
93:                         </div>
94: <div style="width:900px;float:left;margin-left:29px;margin-top:15px;"><p style="width:500px; float:left;font-weight:bolder;font-size:12px;margin-left:20px;font-family:verdana;">Find den billigeste a-kasse - Vælg din  a-kasse og se om du kan spare penge</p>
95: <%= simple_form_for(@konkurrancer, :url => '/finder', :method => "post") do |f| %>
96:   <%= f.association :konkurrancer, :collection => Konkurrancer.all(:order => 'name'), :prompt => "Pick company" %>
97:   <%= f.button :submit, :style => 'display: none;' %>
98: <% end %>
```

My Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // send form ved klik paa listen
    $('option').click(function ()
    {
        var form=$(this).closest('form');
        $.ajax({
          type:'post',
          url:form.attr('action'),
          data:form.serialize(),
          success:function(msg){
            $('#formcontent').html(msg);
          }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Might want to mention a problem or error.

Comment: I have updated my question with the error

Comment: You probably need to pass an object to `simple_form_for`. It Is looking for a model in the first argument, but a hash is passed. See the source here: https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/blob/master/lib/simple_form/action_view_extensions/form_helper.rb#L32

Comment: Should it be an instant variable ? If yes how do I point the form to the correct route ?

Comment: My mistake, :url => {:controller => "finder"} should be :url => "/finder".

Comment: I get a new error in view. I have posted it in the question

Comment: What do you want your form to do?

Comment: I want my form to go to the URL of the submitted option. Example if I select ASE and submit the form. I would go to /finder/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, since you want a jump navigation with a menu you can implement it something like this, just to give you an idea. It uses javascript and jquery by default but has a fallback if javascript isn't available.

In your view:

```
<%= form_tag "/finder/", :method => "get" %>
<%= label_tag :jump_nav, "Company" %>
<%= select_tag(:id, options_for_select(Konkurrancer.all(:order => 'name').collect { |k| [k.name, k.id] }), :id => "jump_nav") %>
<%= submit_tag "Jump to company", :id => "jump_nav_submit" %>
```

In your application.js or if you are using 3.1 assets, place in appropriate file.

```
$().ready(function() {
    $('#jump_nav_submit').hide();
});

$('#jump_nav').live('change', function() {
    window.location = "\/finder\/" + $(this).val();
});
```

Make sure jquery and application are included in your javascript_include_tags.

Then finally in your controller. Using a prepare statement will help prevent a SQL injection.

```
def pricecompare
  @akasse = Konkurrancer.first(:conditions => ["id = ?", params[:id]])
end
```

I have no idea what Konkurrancer means so adjust labels accordingly.

Comment: I have updated my post with my old jquery ajax request. Can you show my have to make an ajax requist with the current Jquery code?

Comment: I think that is beyond the scope of this question which has already strayed far away from the initial problem as the title suggests.

Comment: I understand I will create a new question for that